# Only apply modifyResponseBody for certain content-type

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using `GatewayFilterSpec.modifyResponseBody` (marked as a "BETA" feature) to rewrite JSON payloads. This works well as long as the response payloads are in fact of content-type `application/json`. In my case, that is unfortunately not always guaranteed, and I would like it to only apply the `modifyResponseBody` if the reponse has the `Content-Type: application/json` header, else skip the filter. Is this possible with Spring Cloud Gateway, and how to do this? Thank you.

Now I'm getting this:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$null$11(BodyInserters.java:329)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$bodyInserterFor$12(BodyInserters.java:325)
```

Comment: add a prior predicate that checks the content type header?

Comment: Do you mean like `PredicateSpec.header`? That is a check on the request, isn't this? I'm talking about `Content-Type` on the response being the determining factor. I know there could be a corresponding `Accept` on the request, but I have no expectation that clients reliably set that header. (I may be misguided about all of this, I'm sure you'd tell me...)

Comment: Ah response. Not currently possible.

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the response. But could you point me to some other way of achieving the desired result, even if it means *not* using the convenience of `GatewayFilterSpec.modifyResponseBody`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "solution", one that has all sorts of **problems**:

```
package my_package;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

@Component
@Primary
public class JsonOnlyModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory extends ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory {
    public JsonOnlyModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory(ServerCodecConfigurer codecConfigurer) {
        super(codecConfigurer);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new MyModifyResponseGatewayFilter(config);
    }

    public class MyModifyResponseGatewayFilter extends ModifyResponseGatewayFilter {
        MyModifyResponseGatewayFilter(Config config) {
            super(config);
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
            ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse = getServerHttpResponseFromSuper(exchange);
            ServerHttpResponseDecorator responseDecorator = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(exchange.getResponse()) {
                @Override
                public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                    if (APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(getDelegate().getHeaders().getContentType())) {
                        return serverHttpResponse.writeWith(body);
                    }
                    return super.writeWith(body);
                }
            };
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(responseDecorator).build());
        }

        private ServerHttpResponse getServerHttpResponseFromSuper(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
            ServerHttpResponse[] serverHttpResponse = new ServerHttpResponse[1];
            //noinspection UnassignedFluxMonoInstance
            super.filter(exchange, chain -> {
                serverHttpResponse[0] = chain.getResponse(); // capture the response when the super sets it
                return null;
            });
            return serverHttpResponse[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The chosen approach is in lieu of just changing a copy of the existing `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory`. This allows version upgrades of Spring Boot Gateway to bring in minor changes of `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory`. But since `JsonOnlyModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` is very dependent on the implementation of `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory`, this may easily get broken. Another flaw of this solution is that I had to put an `@Primary` annotation to avoid a `required a single bean, but 2 were found` exception, but it overrides the default which would presumably affect other uses of `modifyResponseBody`. It's ugly to call `super.filter` and not use its result. And so on. So, while this "works", it doesn't, well, fill me with joy.